# How to block magento hack attempts

Tags: php, mysql, apache, magento

Today someone from a RIPE ip address decided to attack my dedicated magento server with repeated attempts to call the add to cart url.

This resulted in overloading the mysql server and causing all magento sites on this server to crash.

Here is an example of the http traffic I was able to find in the apache log:

> X.X.X.X - - [01/May/2016:19:56:33 -0500] "POST /checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5jY3R2Y2FtZXJhd29ybGQuY29tLzQtY2N0di1jYW1lcmEtc3lzdGVtLTgwMHR2bC5odG1s/product/3451 HTTP/1.1" 503 1136 "http://www.domain.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.63 Safari/537.36"

This is causing the sites to crash. Do you have any thoughts on how I can block this kind of traffic using a cronjob script to scan the apache logs for similar type traffic occurring in a short period of time?

I have `fail2ban` and `modsecurity` installed on this server, but this traffic did not trigger an alert in either.

Comment: [RIPE](https://www.ripe.net) is one of the main bodies allocating addresses. You could write a cron task to look through your log for this attack pattern and block them automatically, or write custom fail2ban rules.

Comment: Adjust your fail2ban settings with something that WILL trigger an alert.

Comment: check your site here : https://www.magereport.com/ and make sure you install all security patches.

Comment: Thank  you all for your comments. Is there a good resource to use as a starting point to learn how to write fail2ban rules?